# lint issue of importing .css file in .tsx file

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, next.js, tsx

I tried importing .css file in my .tsx file with help of this [link](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx)

Everything is working fine except for ts-lint error.

I'm importing .css file like:

`import style from './index.css'`

But it's giving lint error of `Cannot find module './index.css'`

Comment: Is the css file located on the same directory as your js file?

Comment: @DenzDacs yes it is in the same directory and even its code applying on the page.
the issue is only lint error.